# catalytic converter

Tags: kia, catalytic-converter, rio

i have 170,000 miles on my car, no problems driving, but my check engine light is on. i took it to a auto parts shop and it read that I needed a knock sensor or catalytic converter, so I changed the knock sensor check engine light is still on, is it possible that I need a new catalytic converter or can it be a sensor?

Comment: Did you clear the error after replacing the knock sensor? On most cars you have to reset the check engine light once it goes on. What is the make, model, year and engine of the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Assuming you didn't clear the codes, on *some* cars you can clear the codes by disconnecting **both** battery cables, and then reconnecting them. The CEL codes are similar to the clock on the dashboard: the car "forgets" them both when you unplug the battery.

Comment: Before doing the solution prvided by @Sam make sure you have the radio code...